# booting from live device space probelm

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, data-recovery, liveusb

I am trying to perform data-recover recovery using extundelete (which didn't help) and ext4magic on a live USB and it requires me to update, upgrade and install the packages. (and some times apt-get -f install) in order to prepare for the recovery command.

The issue that it's always popping up that disk is almost out of space and I can't install any packages at all, can't even apt-get upgrade.

I tried another media but same issue occurred, could it be something to do with the swap memory? If so, any clue how to resize it without affecting the partition to be restores?

In case it's not the swap memory, what could it possibly be? Do I have to boot as EFI mode instead of USB mode?

Comment: More details would be helpful because it's hard to tell which of many possibilities is the problem.  As user605236's answer describes, it could be that the live session doesn't provide for it.  Or, it could be a "persistent" setup that supports saving content that survives the session but your USB drives lack adequate space.  Or, configuration might be required for where to save things.  Describe all of the hardware, software options (plus add links to the products), error messages (including circumstances), etc.

Comment: If you accept an alternative solution, just download a distro with those tools preinstalled, like [System Rescue CD](https://www.system-rescue-cd.org/).

Answer (score 0):

From my (admittedly limited) experience, the problem is that with a live USB there is in effect only one partition exactly the size of the disk image used to create it. To the best of my knowledge, there is no solution because live USBs were not meant to be used like full systems. What you could try doing is fully installing an OS to your USB and then installing ext4magic on that.

To answer your other questions:

This has nothing to do with swap, swap is disk space used as RAM, and your problem here is not too little RAM.

There is no such thing as "USB mode", EFI refers to the type of firmware interface on your computer, not the type of storage device your live image is on.